# Optimal settings for easing eye strain with an old CRT monitor

Tags: display, external-display, crt

**My problem**

I usually use an LCD monitor and have been for quite a long time. Suddenly yesterday my LCD monitor starting displaying all negative or inverted color images and is useless.

For various reasons I cannot get a replacement LCD monitor very easily, so I have to use an old CRT monitor that is available. There are settings available on this old CRT monitor which I've included below too.

**Question**

What settings might I want to use from these options to help ensure it's optimized to reduce eye strain since I have to look at it for long periods of time for school, research, coding, and so on every day.

**Other Detail**

- Unlike my LCD monitor which had certain presets for eye friendly
  outputs (like read mode, mild, soft ...) there are no such things
  here.
- Would adjusting the RGB values be helpful for this reason any

**Here is the menu with pops up in the CRT monitor.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Change it to 75 Hz to be easier on your eyes if you are using US electricity at least. I recall that always helping ease the strain on my eyes while looking at those old school monitors for long period of time.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I don't know I how to change it. I am in India. Do not know whether it uses US tech or not

Comment: The 'Information' screen you provided, option #2, try #4 too and see what happens. Not sure Hz of your country electricity and the effect; maybe the same. We are all human so just give things a try and see.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh I think a mod closed this a bit too soon to not even give you a chance to correct it. In any case, I don't know your history either. I went ahead and adjusted since I know exactly what you are saying and speak English as first language to try to help you get this opened back up. I don't need to put an answer on it either, since Tetsujin indicates the detail I was referring too. I am curious if there's any factual science why this works for humans with the refresh rate and how the eyes see and such.

Answer (score 3):

Where it says 6500, does that have options? That's your colour temperature, in Kelvin. Higher numbers are 'bluer' lower are more red/yellow.

Lower temperature would be more 'relaxing' at cost of definition/accuracy [which I assume you're not too bothered about temporarily]

btw, there really is very little [to no] evidence that colour causes 'harm'. The whole 'Ooh! blue make you go blind' is complete & utter tosh. Reducing blue light can help prepare you for sleep, but that's about all it does. Reducing overall brightness is only useful when your ambient lighting is lower. It doesn't 'magically make you live longer'. Social media has a lot to answer for on pseudo-science ;-)

As noted in comments, see if you can get the refresh rate higher - probably on your computer's graphics control panel rather than on the display settings. 60Hz is a bit flickery on an old CRT, even though it's fine on a modern LCD.

Comment: there is an RGB option (the third one) but the color temperature of 6300 K is a preset

Comment: TBH, with such an elderly monitor, I'd just mess with brightness & contrast until you're as close to happy as you can get. As mentioned in comments above, use your computer's control panel to see if it has a higher refresh rate than 60Hz [that's fine on a modern LCS, but irritating on a CRT]

Answer (score 1):

I do not think monitor colours or brightness harm your eyes, but settings might easily cause fatigue.

I have not used a CRT monitor for some years, but I have a CRT instrument in the basement.

I would turn Contrast (crispness, focus, sharpness) up and Brightness down (mid-range or lower). Brightness is beam power and that is what can cause fatigue.

Colour is your choice. Pick it so as to be a bit warmer (more red, less blue).  My own machine has a night light setting and night light is warmer. Warmer can feel better.

Work to your own choices but the above should be a decent guide.